# Asterisk undefined symbol with new module

Tags: c, asterisk

Having this module as below:

```
#include <time.h>
#include "asterisk/module.h"
#include "asterisk/logger.h"
#include "asterisk/res_resetqueuestats.h"

static unsigned int interval = 1;

int set_stats(const char *queuename){
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "SET STATS CALLED FOR %s", queuename);
    return 0;
}

static void write_log(void)
{
   time_t now = time(NULL);
   struct tm *tm_now = localtime(&now);
   ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Current time interval: %02d:%02d\n", tm_now->tm_hour, tm_now- 
   >tm_min);
}

static void* log_thread(void* data)
{
  while (1) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm_now = localtime(&now);
    if (tm_now->tm_min % interval == 0) {
        write_log();
    }
       usleep(60 * 1000 * 1000);
   }
 return NULL;
}

static int load_module(void)
{
   ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Loading Reset Queue Statistics module.\n");

   pthread_t thread;
   if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, log_thread, NULL) != 0) {
      ast_log(LOG_ERROR, "Failed to create log thread.\n");
      return AST_MODULE_LOAD_FAILURE;
   }
  return AST_MODULE_LOAD_SUCCESS;
}

static int unload_module(void)
{
   ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Unloading Reset Queue Statistics module.\n");
   return 0;
}

AST_MODULE_INFO_STANDARD(ASTERISK_GPL_KEY, "Reset Queue Statistics");
```

The Header File:

```
#define _RES_RESETQUEUESTATS_H

#include <asterisk.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "asterisk/module.h"
#include "asterisk/logger.h"

int set_stats(const char *queuename);

#endif
```

I am trying to call the **set_stats** method from **app_queue.c** but I get: *Error loading module 'app_queue.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/app_queue.so: undefined symbol: set_stats* error. The header file is included in app_queue.c and the module it self loads and runs correctly as I can see the log every minute as configured.

Where I Call it in `app_queue.c`:

```
// My module header file
// ... other includes
// In the end of includes 
#include "asterisk/res_resetqueuestats.h"
//...
static void handle_hangup(void *userdata, struct stasis_subscription *sub,
        struct stasis_message *msg)
{
    struct queue_stasis_data *queue_data = userdata;
    struct ast_channel_blob *channel_blob = stasis_message_data(msg);
    RAII_VAR(struct ast_channel_snapshot *, caller_snapshot, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
    RAII_VAR(struct ast_channel_snapshot *, member_snapshot, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
    RAII_VAR(struct ast_channel *, chan, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
    enum agent_complete_reason reason;

    ao2_lock(queue_data);

    if (queue_data->dying) {
        ao2_unlock(queue_data);
        return;
    }

    if (!strcmp(channel_blob->snapshot->uniqueid, queue_data->caller_uniqueid)) {
        reason = CALLER;
    } else if (!strcmp(channel_blob->snapshot->uniqueid, queue_data->member_uniqueid)) {
        reason = AGENT;
    } else {
        ao2_unlock(queue_data);
        return;
    }

    chan = ast_channel_get_by_name(channel_blob->snapshot->name);
    if (chan && (ast_channel_has_role(chan, AST_TRANSFERER_ROLE_NAME) ||
             !ast_strlen_zero(pbx_builtin_getvar_helper(chan, "ATTENDEDTRANSFER")) ||
             !ast_strlen_zero(pbx_builtin_getvar_helper(chan, "BLINDTRANSFER")))) {
        /* Channel that is hanging up is doing it as part of a transfer.
         * We'll get a transfer event later
         */
        ao2_unlock(queue_data);
        return;
    }

    caller_snapshot = ast_channel_snapshot_get_latest(queue_data->caller_uniqueid);
    member_snapshot = ast_channel_snapshot_get_latest(queue_data->member_uniqueid);

    ao2_unlock(queue_data);

    ast_debug(3, "Detected hangup of queue %s channel %s\n", reason == CALLER ? "caller" : "member",
            channel_blob->snapshot->name);

    ast_queue_log(queue_data->queue->name, queue_data->caller_uniqueid, queue_data->member->membername,
            reason == CALLER ? "COMPLETECALLER" : "COMPLETEAGENT", "%ld|%ld|%d",
        (long) (queue_data->starttime - queue_data->holdstart),
        (long) (time(NULL) - queue_data->starttime), queue_data->caller_pos);

    send_agent_complete(queue_data->queue->name, caller_snapshot, member_snapshot, queue_data->member,
            queue_data->holdstart, queue_data->starttime, reason);
    update_queue(queue_data->queue, queue_data->member, queue_data->callcompletedinsl,
            queue_data->starttime);
    
    // My Call
    int result = set_stats(queue_data->queue->name);
    remove_stasis_subscriptions(queue_data);
}
```

Comment: And when you searched all your installed libraries, using nm or objdump, to see which one defines this symbol, what where the results of your search?

Comment: The symbol is declared in my custom module, and I need to call it from the existing asterisk app_queue.c

Comment: You tagged your question both C and C++. Better remove one of the tags before the flood of comments pointing out how they're different languages washes you away.

Comment: Then your module must export this symbol, and it must be loaded, first, before loading this module.

Comment: __attribute__((visibility("default"))) int set_stats(const char *queuename); something like this ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the .c file with your main function, i.e. `#include` statements and how you attempt to call this function.

Comment: @ryyker modified the post, included the part where I try to make the call

Comment: that's the name of the queue (string), read from the struct queue, that part is ok

Comment: How is your module linked with the failing code?

Comment: _"that's the name of the queue (string)..."_.  Yeah, that comment was my  mis-interpretation.  It is deleted

Comment: @stark not sure what you mean (my bad, not a C developer sorry), but I was hoping to have the possibility in my new module, a method reached from outside, in this case from  the app_queue.c

Comment: Regarding `static void handle_hangup(`, Static functions in C are functions that are restricted to the same file in which they are defined.  I wonder if that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Remove `static` modifier from `static void handle_hangup(void *userdata,...){...}` and see if that changes anything.  (and anywhere else where you need inter-module scope for functions being called.)

Comment: @ryyker It's something that I have noticed and to avoid this I created a non static wrapper method that basically returned the static method, the same issue occurred. However this means trying to call from my module the static method, in fact I am trying the opposite, from the static method I am trying to call set_stats a non static method

Comment: I suggest creating a mini-example of what you are attempting to do. (i.e. circumnavigate the defined behavior of `static` defined functions.) Create a main.c, to call functions, and 1 module defining `static` functions, finally a header file containing the prototypes  (which btw do not require the `static` keyword).  Then test your circumnavigation techniques in this small scoped test code.  This will help you to easily determine the root cause of what you are seeing while removing all of the other potential red-herrings that may be distracting you away from seeing root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Thats common happens with asterisk when you have binary from rpm packages running your library compiled. Or if you not added your module to linker.

Proposed checklist is

1. ensure you have removed all asterisk related .so files and asterisk binary.
2. reinstall again.
3. ensure all libs are in ld.so.conf paths and run ldconfig.
4. ensure your module is loaded BEFORE app_queue or it is linked in app_queue.so(see makefile).
5. check output of

> ldd app_queue.so

That was answer for question. About task itself - you can get it MUCH MUCH simpler way just by reading about hangup handlers in dialplan, no C/C++ code needed at all.

Comment: Removed .so files, reinstalled, ran ldconfig. Output of ldd app_queue.so:  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc30325000) libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f527f0f0000) libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f527ef30000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f527f15d000)

Comment: also created file res_resetqueuestats.exports.in:  {
 global:
  LINKER_SYMBOL_PREFIXset_stats;
 local:
  *;
};